# I am attempting to sort a single hand of cards by rank and suit with no builtins in Python 3 using the code I have

Tags: python

I have outlined where in the code I am having trouble. I am a python newb and require some help. What I would like to do is deal a single hand of cards and then sort the cards using selection sort by suit and rank. I hoped to assign each card its own value and then to compare cards to eventually complete the sort. Currently when I run the code I get an error that states my string index is out of range. I am assuming that this is because I have not properly defined the card1 card2 indices but I am not sure on how to fix them.  Thanks in advance!
edit: for card1 and card2 I would like to be able to compare them based on their rank and if I get a positive number I know that card1 is greater than card2 and if negative I know that card1 is less than card2. I can then use that in the find_largest to compare the 13 cards.

```
import random

def shuffle_deck():
    result = []
    for suit in ['H', 'C', 'D', 'S']:
        for value in ['A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'T', 'J', 'Q', 'K']:
            result += [value + suit];
    random.shuffle(result)
    return result

def deal_hand(n, deck):
    hand = []
    for i in range(n):
        card = deck.pop()
        hand += [card]
    return hand

# This is where the trouble I'm having begins as I'm not sure what cards to compare
def compare(card1,card2):
    value = 'A23456789TJQK'
    suit = 'HCDS'
    card1 = value.find(card1[0] [0]) + ((suit.find(card1[0][1]))*20)
    card2 = value.find(card2[1] [0]) + ((suit.find(card2[1][1]))*20)
    return(card1 - card2)

def find_largest(hand, n):
    largestIdx = 0
    for i in range(1, n):
# I am also not certain what should be compared in this part. I know it should be the 
#current hand compared to the position of the largest card currently.
        if compare(hand [i], hand[largestIdx]) > 0:
            largestIdx = i
    return largestIdx

def selection_sort(hand):
    for idx in range(len(hand)-1, 0, -1):
        largestIdx = find_largest(hand, idx +1)
        hand[idx], hand[largestIdx] = hand[largestIdx], hand[idx]
    print(hand)
```

edit:

```
selection_sort(deal_hand(13, shuffle_deck()))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Wing IDE 101 5.0\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 1, in <module>
    # Used internally for debug sandbox under external interpreter
  File "C:\Program Files\Wing IDE 101 5.0\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 92, in selection_sort
  File "C:\Program Files\Wing IDE 101 5.0\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 79, in find_largest
  File "C:\Program Files\Wing IDE 101 5.0\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 64, in compare
builtins.IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: I think the reason you are getting downvotes is because it's not clear exactly what problems you are having.  You have pointed us to the location in the code, but it is also helpful to see what output you are getting, and what output you expect to get. This helps make it obvious what you need help with.  I would recommend editing this question with that information.

Comment: Thanks SethMMorton! I am new to this. All I would like for it to do is print out one list containing the 13 cards sorted in order of suit and rank.

Comment: If there are 13 cards, then I assume `card1` and `card2` would only have 13 elements.  Python is 0-indexed, meaning the first element is `card1[0]`, and the 13th is `card1[12]`.  If you want the last element of a list, the easiest way is `card1[-1]`.  I'm not sure that will solve your problem, but it might fix the `IndexError` (since `card1[14]` probably doesn't exist.).

Comment: The best way to get some help is to figure out the smallest amount of code that reproduces the problem, then post only that.  When there is as much code as you have posted, it makes it difficult to determine what is actually contributing to the problem and it makes people less likely to try and help.

Comment: I really do appreciate you feedback. I think because I am so new to Python that I am not able to verbalize appropriately for this forum. I have used the shuffle_deck() to create and shuffle a deck of cards. I then want to deal a hand(deal_hand) and then take the cards I have in hand and compare each card assigning it a rank (compare function) I then want to run selection_sort which will pull all of it together and sort the cards. (convoluted I'm very sure but currently do not have other tools (learned) to make it shorter). I apologize for being so confusing. I think it is because I am confused

Comment: Are you familiar with a Traceback?  It's the long message that python spits out when there is an error.  It is an *extremely* helpful tool in figuring out what went wrong with your code.  If you are getting an error as you say, you should be seeing a traceback when you run your code.  You should copy and paste at the end of your question so it is obvious to us what is going wrong.

Comment: I have done so now. Thank you for being so patient with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am following your code correctly, the variables `card1` and `card2` should contain some string like `'AC'` or `'5D'`.  It looks like you want to look at the suit and the number separately (`value.find(card1[0] [0]) + ((suit.find(card1[0][1]))*20)`).  You only need one index here, not two.  Check out the below example:

```
>>> a = 'AC'
>>> a[0]
'A'
>>> a[1]
'C'
>>> a[0][0]
'A'
>>> a[0][1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: string index out of range
```

The string `'C'` has only one element, so when you do `card1[0][1]` you get an index error.  You want to replace that code with

```
card1 = value.find(card1[0]) + ((suit.find(card1[1]))*20)
card2 = value.find(card2[0]) + ((suit.find(card2[1]))*20)
```

That should get rid of your `IndexError`.

Comment: thank you so much! I see now where I was going wrong! I greatly appreciate the time you took to correct me!